# Python Panda - Renaming Double Layer Names back to Single after using .AGG

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

When creating an output using **.agg** and specifying multiple functions, you end up creating a double layer name - so for example ["Points", "std"] which is the standard deviation of the variable Points.

However I want to merge this data back to master data set where everything is at the single level, how do I change this name back to something that's compatible like "Points_STD". Logically I have tried using **.rename** to reference as above but it just doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

So this bit works :

```
df_K = df4.groupby(["Team"]).agg({
            'Shots' : ['mean', 'std']
        }).reset_index()

df_K["STD2"] = df_K["Shots", "std"] / df_K["Shots", "mean"]
```

This doesn't :

```
df_K.rename(columns = {"Shots", "std":'Shots_Std' }, inplace = True)
```

[p.s Picture as referred to in comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRG9x.png)

Comment: do you have any code example?

Comment: have added this to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.agg` to separate each of them, it will not be multi-indexed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Team Player Shots
A a 2
A b 3
A c 5
B e 1
B f 6
B g 7
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df_K = df.groupby(["Team"])['Shots'].agg(Shots_mean='mean', Shots_std='std')
df_K["STD2"] = df_K["Shots_std"] / df_K["Shots_mean"]

df_K.reset_index(inplace=True)

    Team    Shots_mean  Shots_std   STD2
0   A   3.333333    1.527525    0.458258
1   B   4.666667    3.214550    0.688832
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I just copy and paste the 1st line but now I get a key error, my original line still works however.

Comment: What kind of error is the error? I've reposted the code, including the sample data I created.

Comment: That's my fault, I must've copied it wrong as it works now - it's half sorted it, I can definitely see that the name reference is fine, but the merge part still doesn't work because the "Team" variable isn't picked up (None of [Team] are in the columns) - I think this is because the data set still looks multi-indexed but with a blank before the Team and a blank after the derivations? I'll attach an pic in my update. Thanks again btw

Comment: Just to add to this the following line will bring up the error: print(df_K[['Team']])

Comment: Fix code to break multi-indexing Is this acceptable to you?

Comment: Yes, thanks for this - seems the reset_index actually removes all the extraneous "blank indexes", not mentioned in any beginner's guide. Cheers